# Twig ternary operator disabled input

Tags: symfony, twig

Hello so I am using twig templating and ternary operator for a simple condition that if `t.lv1_1 is not empty` then the input will get disabled. Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" value="{{t.lv1_1}}" name="txt_1" class="form-control" style="text-align:center;" {{ t.lv1_1 != "" ? disabled : '' }}>
```

Now my problem is the code doesn't seem to work, I guess I am missing something or doing something wrong. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `disabled` should be a string:

```
... style="text-align:center;" {{ t.lv1_1 != '' ? 'disabled' : '' }}>
```